# Intellij Doesn't Honor maven-compiler-plugin

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have 3 JDK's installed on my computer and Intellij knows about all 3 (6, 7, & 8)

Most projects I work on need 6 but a few need 7 or 8 (we are slowly moving everything to 8)

Maven supports this just fine with the maven-compiler-plugin configured just like here:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html

This works fine from the command line. However Intellij doesn't listen to that plug in and seems to use what it thinks is right. (by default it always goes with Java 8 because it's the last in the list I think)

Is there a way to force Intellijs compiler to use the plug-in? Or a way for everyone to share that configuration across machines and developers?

Answer (score 2):

A few things might be happening, but IDEA *should* honor the maven-compiler-plugin settings. Have you re-imported your Maven project?

1.) Check to see if the language level settings are in sync, if you open up the Project Structure window (**Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S**) do the project AND module's language level mirror the Maven compiler's version?

2.) Now check your Run Configuration, hit **Ctrl+Alt+A** and type "Edit Configurations".

3.) Add a new Maven Configuration with the desired lifecycle phase, then open up the runner tab and deselect "Use project settings". Select your JDK from the dropdown.

4.) Click OK and hit **Shift+F10** to run that new Maven Configuration. Does it work as expected?